# Unix :: AWK removed unexpectedly first line

Tags: bash, awk

I have created a script to extract some links from website.
My script is replacing the 'é' by 'e' by extracting latest text after the pipe.
However when executing it, it strips first line

```
#!/bin/bash

input="links"
    while IFS= read -r line
    do
        awk -F "/" ' { print $6} '  |  iconv -f utf8 -t ascii//TRANSLIT//IGNORE > output_downloads.txt
    done < "$input"
```

File **links**

```
https://DOMAIN.tv/video/9462/sortilégio-capitulo-1
https://DOMAIN.tv/video/9463/sortilégio-capitulo-2
```

**head output_downloads.txt**

```
sortilegio-capitulo-2
sortilegio-capitulo-3
sortilegio-capitulo-4
sortilegio-capitulo-5
```

I don't understand why - considering all lines in source file are similar.
Any idea please ?

*Other questions:*

1. Instead of hard coding the number of last '/', how could i extract it generically ?
2. I would like to have some padding as well - i found this way to do it

```
printf "%04d\n
```

But it works only if format is only numeric.

Any ideas please?

Thanks !!

Comment: `> output_downloads.txt` you overwrite output each loop. `Other questions` Please one question per question `how could i extract it generically ?` just `basename` `it works only if format is only numeric.` and `%s` works for strings.

Comment: Switch from `>` to `>>`.

Comment: @Cyrus, that change is only appropriate if the OP is really going to be calling awk more than once in a loop. Their current code _doesn't_ invoke awk more than once, since the first awk invocation consumes all the input, so the second `read` fails and the loop never runs again; and fixing the code involves removing the loop altogether, so still no reason to use `>>`.

Comment: @FranckDeny, ...one thing to keep in mind is that when you start `awk` inside a `while read` loop, you're running _a whole new copy of `awk` for each time `read` succeeded_. So, whereas you _could_ put a `<<<"$line"` on the `awk` command to make it actually use the line that `while read` read in (and not consume other lines instead), doing that would make your code extremely slow (starting new copies of awk over and over and over instead of running awk just once), and also mean you'd need to worry about the difference between overwriting and appending to your output file.

Comment: @FranckDeny, ...and consider the "one question to a question" rule reiterated. We already have knowledge base entries that cover the other aspects, like selecting only the last field with awk; a question that asked about that again would be closed as a duplicate, and a question that asks about that _in addition to_ something else is eligible to be closed as "too broad".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your awk alone works:

```
#!/bin/bash
awk -F "/" ' { print $NF} ' links |  iconv -f utf8 -t ascii//TRANSLIT//IGNORE > output_downloads.txt
```

You can use $NF instead of $6

Answer (score 2):

Take out the `while read` loop entirely. That loop reads content *into the shell* one line at a time.

However, in your usage mode, `read` only runs once, consuming the *first* line and storing it in `$line`; all the other lines are still available for awk to read -- so awk, when run through that loop the one time, reads all the other lines, writes the 6th column to its stdout, which `iconv` then reads. When the `while read` loop evaluates its condition again, `read` fails (since `awk` read all the available input and there's nothing left), so the loop exits.

Because that first line was consumed by `read line`, it's unavailable for `awk` to see -- which is why it never shows up in your output.

```
awk -F "/" ' { print $6} ' <"$input" \
  | iconv -f utf8 -t ascii//TRANSLIT//IGNORE \
  > output_downloads.txt
```